# Do I need to merge assignments in a flow on the same record or not?

Tags: visual-workflow, after-trigger

I am running an after record flow
[image]

Within the flow, both 'Update record' update the same record.

My question: should I 'merge' both updates to reduce DML ? or the flow engine does that for me?

Is it like flow bulkify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulkification occurs once for each of the Update elements as per sfdcfox answer. What I do when faced with this situation is the following:

- Define a new record variable for `Account`, call it `UpdatedAccount`
- Define a boolean variable `Has Account Changed?`, default `false`
- In the first decision path, assign to `UpdatedAccount.Id` field the value of `$Record.Id` plus `Health State` to its new value.
- Assign `TRUE` to `Has Account Changed`
- In the second decision path, assign to `UpdatedAccount.Id` field the value of `$Record.Id` plus `Level` to its new value.
- Assign TRUE to `Has Account Changed`

Then, at the end of the flow, use a new Decision element to test `Has Account Changed?`. If `TRUE`, Add an Update element using record value `UpdatedAccount` as the source.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought is happening, and your solution is how I usually write the code.

Answer (score 1):

Flow bulkification works on blocking elements. If it is possible for the conditions to reach each of the two elements individually, you should try to update the records only once, because one DML operation is more efficient than two. Running two DML means twice the DML triggers executing, etc. What this means for you depends on what each sub-element does and the state of the entire system. If you can combine these two update into a single element, I'd suggest you try and do so, but it may not matter if this is already a lightweight object with minimal updates.